# /usr/bin/qemu-kvm missing in qemu-kvm/artful-updates,artful-security,now 1:2.10+dfsg-0ubuntu3.5 amd64

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

Is /usr/bin/qemu-kvm missing in qemu-kvm/artful-updates,artful-security,now 1:2.10+dfsg-0ubuntu3.5 amd64?

I am unable to find /usr/bin/qemu-kvm in any package in the repo.

Comment: As far as I can tell it is just kvm, not qemu-kvm - https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/amd64/qemu-kvm/filelist

Comment: I actually figured out my problem. It was the Emulator line in a VM XML I pulled over from a Fedora install. The reason I was looking for this file is because it did exist in 16.04.

Answer (score 4):

You don't actually need that package. All it does is provide a two-line shell script:

```
$ cat /usr/bin/kvm
#!/bin/sh
exec qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm "$@"
$ _
```